# Вставка ссылки viber на сайт

Tags: html, ссылки, viber

Вставил ссылку на viber `<a class="viber" href="viber://add?number=380683399995"></a>` но при переходе в само приложение viber отображается: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: <a class="viber" href="viber://add?number=380683399995"></a> - ссылка которую вставил

Answer (score 0):

Для **Viber**

телефон в формате +(код страны) номер. + заменить на %2B

Comment: Я так и вставил.

Comment: @DenysTretiak ответ изменил.

Comment: на десктопе не работает, а на мобильной работает.

Comment: @DenysTretiak при переходе нужно открывать переписку с данным номером?

Comment: Добавить его в контакты, как на мобильной. Или переписка или звонок. Любое действие будет приемлимо